# How do I work with these classes?

Tags: c++, header-files

I am new to C++ and I am trying to start a project where every time I create a new instance of the ATM class it incements accountID by 1 and displays the current account ID.
This is my code:

```
// Bank ATM.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ATM.h"


int main()
{
    ATM abunch[15];
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        abunch[i] = ATM();
    }
    return 0;
}


//ATM.h
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #ifndef atm
#define atm
class ATM {
    static int accountID;

public:
    ATM();
};
int ATM::accountID = 0;
#endif


//ATM.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ATM.h"
#include <iostream>
ATM::ATM() {
    ++accountID;
    std::cout << accountID;
}
```

I get The following error message:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Move `int ATM::accountID = 0;` into the .cpp file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `ATM::accountID` is declared in a `.h` file, outside of a class, it is globally declared every time that file is included in another file.  You include it twice; in `main.cpp` and in `ATM.cpp`.  That's a no-no.

The declaration needs to move to `ATM.cpp`

```
//ATM.h
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #ifndef atm
#define atm
class ATM {
    static int accountID;

public:
    ATM();
};
int ATM::accountID = 0;   // <--- remove this line
#endif


//ATM.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ATM.h"
#include <iostream>
int ATM::accountID = 0;   // <----put it here
ATM::ATM() {
    ++accountID;
    std::cout << accountID;
}
```

Comment: If I do not #include the header into The BankATM.cpp file it says "identifier not found" on ATM.

Comment: If I put the code into ATM.cpp doesn't that mean I have to #include ATM.cpp into BankATM.cpp which would couuse the compiler to unneedingly copy code over.

Comment: @DustinSmith, I updated my answer.